# Angular8 Cannot read property 'once' of undefined' inside a promise

Tags: angular

I have a service like this:

```
 export class ElectronService {
      public ipc: IpcRenderer

      constructor(private snackBar: SnackbarService) {
        if ((<any>window).require) {
          try {
            this.ipc = (<any>window).require('electron').ipcRenderer
          } catch (error) {
            throw error
          }
        } else {
          console.warn('not for this platform')
        }
      }
      async getFiles(plaques: string[]) {
        new Promise<string[]>((resolve, reject) => {
          this.ipc.once("getFilesResponse", (event, arg) => {
            resolve(arg);
          });
          this.ipc.send("getFiles", plaques);
        });

      }
    }
```

but I get this error

> Cannot read property 'once' of undefined'

the problem I think is that because I am creating a new promise, this keyword is dedicated to Promise, but i have defined a variable "self" and defined it as the this keyword but I still got the same error. any ideas?

Comment: It's not a problem with `this`, or the promise constructor, `=>` is statically scoped. Your use of the import is probably invalid in some way, i.e. `ipcRenderer` isn't exported by `electron` or `window.require` isn't present.

Comment: Well, the error itself ought to be clear enough. The `IpcRenderer` is either not being defined at all (you do have it wrapped in an if-statement, after all), or is being un-defined prior to the invoke of the async. You'll have to do some troubleshooting on your own to figure out why that is the case.